# Sequel ignoring limit

Tags: sql, ruby, sinatra, sequel

I use Sequel and Sinatra with Sequel. Sequel properly inserts records, but I'm struggling with deleting. When I use:

```
Product.where(:name=>"Book").limit(10).delete
```

it deletes absolutely every record which fulfills condition. It seems to completely ignore limit. Do you have any idea what the reason can be?

Answer (score 0):

There are very few databases that support `DELETE LIMIT` (I think MySQL is the only one).

Sequel's default behavior is to ignore the limit setting during `DELETE`.  On MySQL, it considers it as a database-specific extension.

Comment: thank you, I was under impression it should work as it was presented in Sequel documentation. Is there any way to gain the same result without limit?

Comment: Where in the Sequel documentation does it state that limit.delete should work?  In terms of the same result, using a subselect should work: `Product.where(:id=>Product.where(:name=>'Book').limit(10).select(:id)).delete`